# Can I use the output of a cell as the cell location in another formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Here's what I have:

Cell D13`=AN` and Cell AE13`=13`

Cell K13 has this formula `=D13&AE13` so K13 outputs "AN13".

From there I would like to have a formula that grabs K13's output(AN13) as a *cell reference* rather than data. Normally I could just use `=Sheet!1AN13` but I need it to get the "AN13" from Cell K13. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&K13))`

[INDIRECT()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) allows you to reference text as a cell address.

Comment: Minus an extra closing parenthesis that is exactly what I needed.